# How do i convert list of data from database through model to javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Hi I am having difficultly to simply just retrieve my list of information from DB, the locations i entered are just hard-coded to check that the markers and google map codes are actually working fine. But i cant seem to read the list i populated, what's wrong?

**Controller**

```
 private SchoolDataGateway schGateway = new SchoolDataGateway();

        public ActionResult Index(School model)
        {
            var schooList = schGateway.SelectAll();
            model.SchooList = schooList;

            return View(model);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model SGSchoolForum.Models.School

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Singapore Map";
}
<h3>@ViewBag.Title.</h3>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

@section scripts {
    <section class="scripts">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var locations = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SchooList))';

        //var locations = [
        //        ['Ahmad Ibrahim Secondary School DUS', 1.43606195493277, 103.829714943973],
        //        ['Anderson Secondary School DUS', 1.37424251206867, 103.851429631622],
        //        ['Ang Mo Kio Secondary School DUS', 1.36733742693541, 103.84215464968],
        //        ['Bartley Secondary School DUS', 1.34001774479212, 103.882454715584],
        //        ['Beatty Secondary School DUS', 1.34179084059088, 103.852018183374]
        //    ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.3520728, 103.8049346),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][8], locations[i][9]),
            map: map
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][3]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
    }
        </script>
    </section>
}
<div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 450px;"></div>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Collections;
[enter image description here][1]
namespace SGSchoolForum.Models
{
    [Table("School")]
    public class School
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "School Code")]
        public string School_Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "School Name")]
        public string School_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cut Off Point")]
        public int School_CutOffPoint { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string School_Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
        public int School_PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DUS Name")]
        public string Dus_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Latitude")]
        public double Dus_Lat { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Longtitude")]
        public double Dus_Long { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Zone")]
        public int Zone_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Area")]
        public int Area_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<School> SchooList { get; set; }

        public School()
        {
            SchooList = new School[] { };
        }
    }

}
```

The error was something like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line javascript for

```
var locations =  '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SchooList))';
```

Comment: remove the single quotes, it should be like `var locations =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SchooList));`

Comment: Have you checked with the debugger if the schools are actually being added to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing our few issues in your code

1) The javascript variable assignment. Change it to

```
var locations = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SchooList));
```

Your previous code would have evaluated the expression and then made the entire thing as a string, as you had wrapped the expression between `'  '`

2) In the code your you have commented the hardcoded value for locations. That reveals that the `locations variable must be of type array of arrays`. But your `SchoolList` is of type array of objects. So even though if you get the variable data to be set properly your code will not work anyways with this data structure.

So the `SchoolList` must be of type `List<string[]>` in your class. That means you must tweek your logic in your controller like below.

```
    public ActionResult Index(School model)
    {
        var schooList = schGateway.SelectAll();
        foreach(var school in schoolList)
        {
           model.SchooList.Add(new string[] {school.School_Name, school.Dus_Lat.ToString(), school.Dus_Long.ToString() });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And for the error 
`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`. This can occur if your `Model` is `null`. Debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should return JSON which you will pass to the javascript.

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(School model)
        {
            var schooList = schGateway.SelectAll();
            model.SchooList = schooList;

            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**View**

In the view you should call that method using AJAX call and save the results to the *locations* variable.

```
var locations;

$.ajax({
  url: "/Home/Index",
}).done(function(data) {
  locations = data;
});
```

Maybe you'll need a bit tweaking but that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON as Agramer said.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
    var schooList = schGateway.SelectAll();

    //Use only what you need
    var result = new {
      locations = //schooList.attribute ,
      otherAttribute = //schooList.otherAttribute 
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
var locations;
var otherData;

$.ajax({
  url: "/your URL",
}).done(function(data) {
  locations = data.location;
  otherData = data.otherAttribute;
  // your code
});
```